# How can I save the plotly graphs as image(png,jpg etc.) offline in python?

Tags: python-2.7, plotly

I want to save plotly offline graphs as static images(jpg,png..) in python. Could you help me about it? 
Thanks in advance.

I tried but It doesn't generate the "test" file.

```
    plotly.offline.plot({"data": dataPanda,
                 "layout": layout1},
                 image='jpeg', image_filename="test", auto_open=False,output_type='file')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs: https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/.

There is a detailed information on how to create static image exports.